Alternative version of Hallelujah (Jeff Buckley / Leonard Cohen)
I heard (there was a secret chord...). No, sorry I heard there was a version of Hallelujah from Jeff Buckley / Leonard Cohen that hasn't got the romantic / kinky lyrics that the original song has.
Also, this version, from what I've heard is more religious / spiritual oriented that the version everyone knows.
Is that a fake info? If not, can anyone give the reference of that more spiritual alternative version?

The first comment on https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/13018/15268 includes a link to 4 sets of lyrics including those by Jeff Buckley. It doesn't appear dramatically different from other Cohen versions to me.

Well at least it includes two chorus I didn't know yet. I'll try to switch the lyric part I don't feel comfortable with, with these.

There's about 35 different takes that are published of versions of hallelujah. Of course the original was Leonard Cohen and of course made famous more recently by Jeff Buckley. So then there's Rufus Wainwright, Lucy Thomas, Alexander Burke, Pentatonix, and Jennifer Hudson they're also seems to be a Carrie Underwood version as well. And basically any person that that can play a terrible version of this song. But just remember if you going to play it at least you have the depth of the structure let Cohen in Buckley perform the song with... Best wishes.
